# Spring oauth server redirect to redirect_uri when coming from 127.0.0.1 but not from localhost (Angular client)

Tags: java, angular, spring-security, openid-connect

I've configured a spring oauth2 server following the spring.io get started documentation. When I initiate a login from an Angular client running on port 4200, when the logging is successfull (ie: correct id and password are given), I get redirected to the redirect_uri of the angular client only when I use 127.0.0.1:4200 to access my angular app. If I come from localhost I get redirect to an error page

[Spring.io doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html)

My spring configuration :

```java
    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
            .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());   // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0
        http
                // Redirect to the login page when not authenticated from the
                // authorization endpoint
                .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(
                                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"))
                )
                // Accept access tokens for User Info and/or Client Registration
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                // Form login handles the redirect to the login page from the
                // authorization server filter chain
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId("bakcup-ui")
                                                            .clientId("backup-ui")
                                                            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.NONE)
                                                            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                                                            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                                                            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                                                            .redirectUri("http://localhost:4200")
                                                            .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:4200")
                                                            .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                                                            .scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
                                                            .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(false).build())
                                                            .build();

        // Save registered client in db as if in-memory
        JdbcRegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository = new JdbcRegisteredClientRepository(jdbcTemplate);
        registeredClientRepository.save(registeredClient);


        return registeredClientRepository;
    }
```

My angular side configuration (using angular-oauth2-oidc) :

```js
export const authConfig: AuthConfig = {
    clientId: 'backup-ui',
    issuer: 'https://localhost:9000',
    redirectUri: window.location.origin,
    responseType: 'code',
    scope: 'openid profile',
    strictDiscoveryDocumentValidation: false,
}
```

The url I get redirected to when coming from localhost:

```
localhost:9000/error?response_type=code&client_id=backup-ui&state=M09hSHdSdC5KSlRfOGlLNDZWa1NQbE05TDFRamJ6NGtwUDludUk0blM1Y1dO&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200&scope=openid%20profile&code_challenge=_LU-Ou9Gr_53_LGDKTz36bJddFr2gndknIrZoC03ZJo&code_challenge_method=S256&nonce=M09hSHdSdC5KSlRfOGlLNDZWa1NQbE05TDFRamJ6NGtwUDludUk0blM1Y1dO&continue
```

[Error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uueG4.png)

If after that I go back to localhost:4200, I land there:

```
localhost:9000/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=backup-ui&state=SUhKQ1BLejFfeUJTalVwUHlpWEVGYURQUDV1M3lsUG5lZElvMjd3QzNRbWJr&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200&scope=openid%20profile&code_challenge=Y-V75oU8Zjsf7lctW9otdkn-U0vML-nGv8v1FCbrM5A&code_challenge_method=S256&nonce=SUhKQ1BLejFfeUJTalVwUHlpWEVGYURQUDV1M3lsUG5lZElvMjd3QzNRbWJr
```

With the same error page (since there is no html in my spring server)

I tried a lot of things but none are working. Even using the sample code from github [spring-authrozation-server](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server) produces the same problem.

Comment: Also, i know there is no issue from Angular side since its works like a charm with Azure or KeyCloak issuer.

Comment: Maybe, this has something to do with https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12307 (same kind of redirection issue from spring-security framework)

Comment: Chek it out: https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/issues/594